# Subrayar palabras en un <p>

Tags: javascript, dom, filtro, replace

¿Cómo puedo filtrar palabras dentro de un `<p>`, subrayarlas, y volver a introducir en el mismo `<p>`?

Comment: ¿Cuál es la útima *vuelta* que le diste y qué resultados o errores obtuviste? La idea del ejercicio es que aprendas, por tanto, muestra el código que has escrito (un ejemplo mínimo y verificable) y a partir de él podremos decirte lo que está mal y ayudarte a resolver el problema. Como entenderás, nadie hará el ejercicio por ti y si lo hace, te impide de aprender, que de eso se trata.

Comment: Es que no quisiera condicionar a quien quiera responder al ejercicio. Tengo las palabras con más de 5 letras en un Array que obtuve mediante algunas funciones o métodos como ya expliqué. El problema es que el texto es "jodido", tiene saltos de línea entre oraciones que se toman como carácteres al igual que los puntos y comas. Complicado de filtrar para obtener solo palabras con más de 5 letras y no palabras de tres letras con una coma y un espacio por ejemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

podrias crear una copia del html xdd y trabajar las palabras en un array:

```js
var parElm = document.getElementsByTagName("P").item(0)
var parHtm = parElm.innerHTML
var parArr = parHtm.split(/[\s,\.,\"]+/)

parArr.forEach(wrd => {
  if (wrd.length > 5) {
    parHtm = parHtm.split(wrd).join(`<u>${ wrd }</u>`)
  }
})
    
parElm.innerHTML = parHtm
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<p>
"There is no one who loves pain itself, who seeks after it and wants to have it, simply because it is pain..." Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum augue arcu, scelerisque in vehicula ac,pellentesque id felis. Maecenas ornare ex rutrum purus rhoncus luctus. Proin non tortor aliquet, consectetur sem eget, tempus mi. Donec in auctor mi, nec imperdiet arcu. Pellentesque egestas enim erat, nec blandit nunc molestie congue. Sed efficitur at sem in mattis. Phasellus quis dui eu ligula consequat posuere.
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Eres increible! Necesito que por favor me expliques como obtuviste ésto:

 `<u>${wrd}</u>`

Comment: `${}` se llama interpolacion de strings y existe en la mayoria de los lenguajes. <u/> es la etiqueta html para subrayar texto. y el split y join son funciones de la clase Array de js para unir y separar arrays. asi vas remplazando la palabra original por la subrayada, al dividir el texto por la palabra que buscas, y volviendolo a unir con la palabra subrayada.

Comment: Ok Estoy entendiendo perfectamente como se aplican los metodos split y join, no habia podido encontrar material acerca de <u/>, existen unas paginas en las que aparecen editores de regexp pero juro que no logro utilizarlos aún. 
Quisiera saber entonces cómo lograste descifrar ésto: `(/[\s,\.,\"]+/);`

Comment: https://regex101.com/  
De hecho estoy revisando tu respuesta mediante ésta Web y me encuentro fascinado del control que tienes sobre el tema. 
Muchas Gracias Rey del RegExp

Comment: te recomiendo el sitio de mozilla, alli esta bien explicado el tema de regexp para js: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions slds

Comment: Una pregunta Dicalj, por qué agregarle el .item(0) en el getElements?

Comment: por el nodelist que retorna nomas xd y obtener el primer parrafo <p/>